# Nested RecyclerView Displaying Only One Item

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I am using Room database and recylerview to display items in Android(Kotlin). Below is my Entity.

```
Entity(tableName = "Note")
@Parcelize
data class Product(
@ColumnInfo(name = "Title") val title: String? = null,
@ColumnInfo(name = "Body") val body: String? = null,
@ColumnInfo(name = "Description") val description: ArrayList<String>?,
@ColumnInfo(name = "Completed") val completed: ArrayList<Boolean>?): Parcelable
```

I am able to display the Parent recycler view properly, but inside it, I am trying to display description and completed as Nested recyclerview, but I am getting only the last item from them, not all of them.
Any help? Thanks in advance.

[Screenshot Attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GPv7W.png)

Comment: Show code of adapter? Fragment?